# Rails : polymorphic association (has_many) exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

trying a has many through association where the join table(UserGroupMembers) is polymorphic. This is on Rails 4

How do I fix this?

On creating a Group with members the exception occurs . ie Join table error

```
User group memberships is invalid
```

code creating a group with users

```
group = Group.new(name: "test")
group.users << User.first
group.valid? (or group.save)
```

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_members, as: :link
  has_many :users, through: :user_group_members, autosave: true
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_members
  has_many :groups , through: :user_group_members, source: :link, source_type: :"Group"
end
```

```
class UserGroupMembers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :link , polymorphic: :true,required: true
  belongs_to :user, required: true
end
```

Comment: `User` is not directly associated with `Group`. It is associated through `user_group_members`. Try to create `user_group_members` for `group` model. `Users` will be automatically accessible

Comment: Group is associated user_group_members via a polymorphic link.

Comment: `User` should also mention `has_many :user_group_members, as: :link`. Can you check this 'https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html'.